# plotting log(10) lengths differ

Tags: r

I am having difficulty plotting a log(10) formula on to existing data points. I derived a logarithmic function based on a list of data where "Tout_F_6am" is my independent variable and "clo" is my dependent variable.
When I go to plot it, I am getting the error that lengths x and y are different. Can someone please help me figure out whats going wrong?

```
logKT=lm(log10(clo)~ Tout_F_6am,data=passive)
summary(logKT) #r2=0.12
coef(logKT)

plot(passive$Tout_F_6am,passive$clo) #plot data points
x=seq(53,84, length=6381)#match length of x variable
y=logKT
lines(x,y,type="l",lwd=2,col="red")

length(passive$Tout_F_6am) #6381
length(passive$clo) #6381
```

Additionally, can the formula `curve(-0.0219-0.005*log10(x),add=TRUE,col=2)`be written as `eq=(10^-0.022)*(10^-0.005*x)`? thanks!

Comment: Regarding your question about the formula: Nope, that's not the same.

Comment: If the answer is useful to you, you can mark it correct by clicking the "tick". See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to plot the model object, not the predictions from the model. Try something like this:

Define the explanatory values you want to plot, in a data frame (or tibble). It doesn't have to be as many as there are data points.

```
library(dplyr)
explanatory_data <- tibble(
  Tout_F_6am = seq(53, 84, 0.1)
)
```

Add a column of predicted values using `predict()`. This takes a model and your explanatory data. `predict()` will return the transformed values, so you have to backtransform them.

```
prediction_data <- explanatory_data %>%
  mutate(
    log10_clo = predict(logKT, explanatory_data),
    clo = 10 ^ log10_clo
  )
```

Finally, draw your plot.

```
plot(clo ~ Tout_F_6am, data = prediction_data, log="y", type = "l")
```

The plotting is actually easier using ggplot2. This should give you more or less what you want.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(passive, aes(Tout_F_6am, clo)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  scale_y_log10()
```